# Why can't the NUnit Test Adapter find my FsUnit tests?

Tags: visual-studio, f#, nunit, test-explorer, fsunit

I'm using Visual Studio Professional 2015 and I have version 2.0.0.0 of the NUnit Test Adapter installed.

It doesn't discover any tests on building the following code:

```
namespace SmallestDivisibleIntegers

module Core =

    let f n = [2..4] |> List.map (fun x -> x + n - n % x)

module Tests =

    open FsUnit
    open NUnit.Framework

    open Core

    [<Test>]
    let ``Correct answers`` () =
        f 1 |> should equal [2; 3; 4]
        f 4 |> should equal [6; 6; 8]
        f 43 |> should equal [44; 45; 44]
        f 123 |> should equal [124; 126; 124]
        f 420 |> should equal [422; 423; 424]
        f 31415 |> should equal [31416; 31416; 31416]
        f 1081177 |> should equal [1081178; 1081179; 1081180]

    [<Test>]
    let ``simple test`` () =
        (1 + 1) |> should equal 2
```

I have referenced FsUnit (2.1.0) and NUnit (3.2.0) and the tests run fine in F# interactive.

How can I get the tests to appear in the Test Explorer?

Comment: Just out of interest, this is for this code golf question: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/79980/smallest-integers-after-n-divisible-by-2-3-and-4

Comment: Yes - note that if you install FsUnit 2.1.0 directly (with Nuget or Paket) it will install the correct version of NUnit.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had the same problem and it is easy to make.

You are pre-supposing that there is only one `NUnit Test Adapter` and that it works for versions 2.x and 3.x of NUnit. However there are two versions of the `NUnit Test Adapter`

one for 2.x: [NUnit Test Adapter](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6ab922d0-21c0-4f06-ab5f-4ecd1fe7175d)

> The NUnitTestAdapter extension works with the Visual Studio Unit Test
>   window to allow integrated test execution under Visual Studio 2012,
>   2013 and 2015.
>
> The latest version, 2.0, is based on NUnit 2.6.4 and is compatible
>   with tests developed using NUnit 2.0 through 2.6.4. It supports all
>   versions of VS2012, VS2013 and VS2015.
>   You can find the release notes [here](http://nunit.org/index.php?p=vsTestAdapterReleaseNotes&r=2.6.4)

and one for 3.x: [NUnit3 Test Adapter](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0da0f6bd-9bb6-4ae3-87a8-537788622f2d)

> The NUnit3TestAdapter extension works with the Visual Studio Unit Test
>   window to allow integrated test execution under Visual Studio 2012,
>   2013 and 2015.
>
> This adapter only works with NUnit 3.0. For use with earlier versions
>   of NUnit use the NUnitTestAdapter (note - no 3) extension.
>
> The current package is the first production release of version 3.0 of
>   the adapter, using NUnit 3.0.1. You can find the documentation and
>   release notes at https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki