# Why am I not able to use the latest version of NUnit and FsCheck with F#?

Tags: f#, nunit, fscheck

I would like to use the latest versions of NUnit, FsCheck, and F#.
However, when I point to the latest versions of my packages, my unit tests do not get discovered.

However, my property-based tests are discovered (i.e. FsCheck).

My packages are the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="FsCheck" version="2.4.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="FsCheck.Xunit" version="2.4.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="FSharp.Core" version="4.0.0.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="FsUnit" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="NUnit" version="3.2.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="xunit.abstractions" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="xunit.extensibility.core" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="xunit.extensibility.execution" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="xunit.runner.visualstudio" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net461" />
</packages>
```

My app.config is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
  </startup>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="nunit.framework" publicKeyToken="96d09a1eb7f44a77" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-9999.9999.9999.9999" newVersion="3.2.1" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Your packages contain both NUnit and xUnit.net. If you want to use NUnit, you should probably start by removing all the xUnit.net packages.

Comment: Thanks Mark. However, I use XUnit with FsCheck (i.e. Property tests).

Comment: Yes, I can see that, but `FsCheck.XUnit` is a Glue Library for xUnit.net. It's not going to work with NUnit.

Comment: By the way, I'm currently reading your blog on Haskell's default support for Port and Adapter architecture. Do you think I am ready to pickup Haskell at my current level of F#?

Comment: I don't know. Sorry to be blunt, but you still seem to be struggling with basic F# problems, but it may be that your knowledge of C# and .NET is in your way. Perhaps Haskell will give you an opportunity for a fresh start. Maybe it'll work out better for you, but personally, I still find learning Haskell *hard*. Then again, I don't think I picked the easiest approach to it either...

Comment: To the anonymous downvoter who seems to downvote all of Scott's questions: if you feel that his questions are bad, then tell him why you think so. Downvoting without further feedback makes it hard for him to improve.

Comment: I appreciate your honesty. Honestly, I'm still searching for an exercise and/or project where these concepts begin to click for me. Until then, I guess I'll just keep practicing the basics on my off hours.

Comment: What are you using to run the test? I use VS Test explorer. I too am still unable to run NUnit 3.x, FsCheck with property test and use VS Test explorer with VS 2015 community. I am pretty sure my problem is the adapter that allows the test to run with VS Test explorer needs to be updated; thus being on the bleeding edge is as they say: bleeding. AFAIK all of those have the source code available, so if you want, dig in, update the code, and give back to the community.

Comment: Of interest: [Why can't the NUnit Test Adapter find my FsUnit tests?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37297238/1243762)

Comment: What is it that you are not getting with F#? Are you consistently getting compile errors, invalid results, or something else? If you and I are on at the same time this would be better in a chat room.

Comment: I don't think Haskell is necessarily any more difficult than F#, just different.  The good thing about it is that you wouldn't have an OO crutch to fall back on, the bad thing is that it'd introduce a lot of new concepts quite quickly.  I'd say if you're interested though, go for it.  I'm very far from a Haskell expert but I think it's a fantastic language, not least as a source of ideas for F# development.

Comment: As for the question at hand, does the FSharp.Core version of the project you are trying to test match the `4.0.0.1` found in that packages.config file?  It's very easy to run into trouble by creating a new F# 4 project and then trying to test it with FsCheck, etc if you don't make sure FSharp.Core binding redirects are set up correctly.

Comment: @ScottNimrod - How did you create this project? By hand, or did you use the Project Scaffold? (https://github.com/fsprojects/ProjectScaffold). I found that I had lots of problems with NuGet until I started using the Project Scaffold to set up my project; it installs Paket instead, which makes sure the right binding redirects are set up. If you're still using NuGet, I'd suggest giving Paket (http://fsprojects.github.io/Paket/) a try.

Comment: The NUnit3TestAdapter worked for me. Thanks. =)

Comment: I keep revisiting this issue and am no longer able to get my test discovery to work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried installing the NUnit3 test adapter so that Visual Studio knows about NUnit? 
https://www.nuget.org/packages/NUnit3TestAdapter

It could be that your FsCheck tests are found because Visual Studio already knows about XUnit.

Comment: (Just noticed that this suggestion is covered in the question that Guy Coder linked to in the comments above. +1 to that.)